# In Angular, I am calling a function from an *ngFor loop and the entire loop runs twice when it should only run once

Tags: angular, typescript

In the html file of application component I am adding an ngFor loop for an array that contains 4 values and creates checkboxes for each. Inside of the for loop I am calling a function in the ts file. The file checks two arrays of the same type. The first one lists all datatypes (the one in the for loop) and the other one only contains datatypes related to an application. If the current datatype from the loop exists in the array containing only datatypes for the application, then the checkbox is checked otherwise it is unchecked. The problem that I have is that the entire loop runs twice and I can't figure out why, I have removed everything in the function and only added a counter and logged it and it was still going from 1 - 8 when there are only 4 values. I also, in the html file, moved the for loop div outside of the form to make sure there wasn't something else affecting it and I got the same results. You can see how its repeating in the last image attached. I am adding an image of the code with comments after the code itself.
application.component.html contains the for loop.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="applicationForm.dirty && appName.invalid">Enter an application name</div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="applicationForm.dirty && description.invalid">Enter a description</div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="!applicationForm.invalid && saveApplication()" #applicationForm="ngForm">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend>Application</legend>
            <label>Application Name</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="application.appName" #appName="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" name="appName" required="required">

            <label>Description</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="application.appDesc" #description="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" name="description" required="required">

            <div class="dropdown">
                <label class="point btn btn-primary" (click)="show = !show">Data Types <span class="caret"></span></label>

                <div *ngIf="show">
                    <div class="box">
                        <br>
                        <div *ngFor="let datatype of datatypes">
                            <span>{{getDatatypes(datatype.description)}}</span>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="datatype{{datatype.dataTypeId}}" name="datatype{{datatype.dataTypeId}}" [value]="datatype.description" [checked]="exists">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label for="datatypes">{{ datatype.description }}</label>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="CancelAction()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

application.component.ts contains rest calls and function, appId != 0 means its an existing application

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Application } from '../main-content/destination-apps-list/destination-apps-list.component';
import { ApplicationDataService } from '../service/data/application-data.service';
import { BasicAuthenticationService } from '../service/basic-authentication.service';
import { Datatype } from '../main-content/destination-apps-list/destination-apps-list.component';
import { AppData } from '../main-content/destination-apps-list/destination-apps-list.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application',
  templateUrl: './application.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string;
  appId: number;
  dataTypeId: number;
  application: Application;
  appData: AppData;
  datatypes: Datatype[];
  checkedDatatypes: Datatype[];
  show = false;
  exists = false;
  appDataId;

  constructor(
    private applicationService: ApplicationDataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
    private basicAuthenticationService: BasicAuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.username = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    this.appId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log('params '+this.route.snapshot.params)
    this.application = new Application(this.appId, '', '', '');
    console.log(this.appId);
    if(this.appId != 0){
      console.log('initializing application component '+this.appId)
      this.applicationService.retrieveApplication(this.username, this.appId).subscribe(
        data => this.application = data
      )

      this.applicationService.retreiveAllDataTypesByAppId(this.username, this.appId).subscribe(
        data => this.checkedDatatypes = data
      )
      
      this.applicationService.retreiveAllDatatypes(this.username).subscribe(
        data => this.datatypes = data
      )

    }

    this.applicationService.retreiveAllDatatypes(this.username).subscribe(
      data => this.datatypes = data
    )   
    

  }
  
  getDatatypes(description){
          let datatype = this.checkedDatatypes.find(element => element.description === description);
          if(typeof datatype !== 'undefined'){
            console.log('datatype: '+datatype.description);
            this.exists = true;          
          } else {
            console.log('I am being called')
            this.exists = false;
          }
  }


  saveApplication(){
    if(this.appId == 0){
      console.log(this.application)
      this.applicationService.createApplication(this.username, this.application).subscribe (
        data => console.log(data)
      )   
      console.log(this.application)

      this.applicationService.createAppDataType(this.username, this.appData).subscribe (
        data => console.log(data)
      ) 
    } 
    else{
      this.applicationService.updateApplication(this.username, this.appId, this.application).subscribe (
        data => console.log(data)
      )

      this.applicationService.updateAppDataType(this.username, this.appDataId, this.appData).subscribe (
        data => console.log(data)
      )

      this.applicationService.deleteAppDataType(this.username, this.appDataId).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
        }
      )
    }
    this.router.navigate([`main-content/${this.username}`])
  }


  CancelAction(){
    this.router.navigate([`main-content/${this.username}`])
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

destination-apps.list.component.ts contains the models

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApplicationDataService } from '../../service/data/application-data.service';
import { BasicAuthenticationService } from '../../service/basic-authentication.service';

export class Application {
  constructor(
    public appId: number,
    public appName: string,
    public appDesc: string,
    public dataTypes: string
  ){
  }
}

export class Datatype {
  constructor(
    public dataTypeId: number,
    public description: string
  ){ }
}

export class AppData {
  constructor(
    public appDataId: {
      appId: number,
      dataTypeId: number
    }
  ){ }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-destination-apps-list',
  templateUrl: './destination-apps-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./destination-apps-list.component.css']
})
export class DestinationAppsListComponent implements OnInit {

  applications: Application[];
  datatypes: Datatype[];
  username: string;
  message: string;
  appId: number;

  constructor(
    private applicationService:ApplicationDataService, 
    private router: Router,
    private basicAuthenticationService: BasicAuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshApplications();
    this.username = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser();
  }

  refreshApplications(){
    this.username = this.basicAuthenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    this.applicationService.retreiveAllApplications(this.username).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.applications = response;
      }
    )


  }

  deleteApplication(appId) {
    console.log(`delete app ${appId}`);

    this.applicationService.deleteApplication(this.username, appId).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.message = `Application ${appId} was Successfully Deleted!`
        this.refreshApplications();
      }
    )
  }

  updateApplication(appId) {
    console.log(`update app ${appId}`);
    this.router.navigate(['applications',appId]);
    this.applicationService.retreiveAllDataTypesByAppId(this.username, appId).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.datatypes = response;
      }
    )
  }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @okan pointed out, Angular's change detection is running twice, causing your *ngFor loop to run twice. This is intentional behavior by the framework when running in development mode, and should not happen in production mode.

While changing the Change Detection Strategy can be a good solution to this problem, I suggest instead that you refactor your code to isolate your app's data more from the UI.

In this case, I would maintain separate arrays for whichever (or maybe both) arrays that are currently negatively affecting your *ngFor loop. Calculate whatever you need to, using the data that is not exposed to the UI. When everything settles, set the data that is exposed to the UI. This way, the *ngFor loop will still run twice (which again, is intended), but it won't cause your calculation to run twice.

In general, I try not to have the UI directly invoke non-trivial code, and try to keep separation between the UI and the data model.

Answer (score 1):

It is Angular's **change detection**.

**For Angular 2+**

You can change **Change Detection Strategy** as follows:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```